# I'm attempting to use jdk.dio on my rpi and I get 'no dio in java.library.path'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, raspberry-pi, deviceiocontrol

I am trying to use the Oracle Device I/O library.

I have made the dio following the instructions on the oracle page and copied the build folder onto by development PC. I added the built jar to my project on my IDE(Intellij IDEA) with the natives I could find. I'm running the program on my RPI using the embedded systems plugin for IDEA. The code can be seen on my github:

Main class:
https://github.com/MAWoodMain/RPITank/blob/master/src/main/java/Main.java

Invoked class:
https://github.com/MAWoodMain/RPITank/blob/master/src/main/java/sensors/MPU9250/MPU9250_Oracle.java

The code is largely irrelevant because my issue is deployment/execution.

Comment: Please show how you are running the application. It looks like you haven't configured the system property `java.library.path` with the location of the native library (or you are missing the native library).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here is an image of the library config:
http://imgur.com/9DtVbmp

Answer (score 1):

After some research I discovered I can specify the native locations in the VM options, the options I used to solve the problem were:

```
-Djava.library.path=/home/pi/dio/dev/build/so/ -classpath .:classes:/home/pi/dio/dev/build/ -Djava.security.policy=/home/pi/gpio.policy -Djdk.dio.registry=/home/pi/dio.properties
```

This also includes the properties and policy files necessary to use DIO.